# how to get selected value from ajax combobox using javascript in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to get the selected value from ajax combobox selected item using javascript in asp.net c#

here is my code

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="dropdown_dest" runat="server" Width="90%" onfocusout="blurFunction()" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="ComboboxWidth" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" Height="15px" MaxLength="50">
</asp:ComboBox>

function blurFunction()
{
     var ddlReport = document.getElementById("<%=dropdown_dest.ClientID%>").value;
     alert(ddlReport);
}
```

in alert it is showing undefined.

Please help me to solve me this error

Thank You.

Comment: Typo: `("%=dropdown_dest.ClientID%>")` is missing the `<`. It should be `("<%= dropdown_dest.ClientID %>")`

Comment: sorry typing mistake

Comment: Try to use `var ddlReport = document.getElementById("dropdown_dest").value;`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, you can do it this way:

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="dropdown_dest" runat="server" Width="90%" onfocusout="blurFunction()" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="ComboboxWidth" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" Height="15px" MaxLength="50">
</asp:ComboBox>

function blurFunction()
{
    var ddlReport = $("#" + "<%=dropdown_dest.ClientID%>").find("option:selected").val();
    alert(ddlReport);
}
```

Comment: @karan it returns undefined even with `$("#" + "<%=dropdown_dest.ClientID%>")` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested.

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="dropdown_dest" runat="server" Width="90%" onfocusout="blurFunction(this)" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="ComboboxWidth" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" Height="15px" MaxLength="50">
</asp:ComboBox>

<script>

function blurFunction(e) {
var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(val);
}
</script>
```

using "this" will skip jquery loop and js script can be put in separate file.